# How to add a UILabel to a scrollview in order to show all the text in the label

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to add 2 UILabels to a scrollview programatically. The text within the UILabel is dynamic, and I dont know what the text will be since it's loaded from a database. Therefore I cant know what size I should set my UILabel. Im using a scrollview to display all the text within each label.

How do I go about doing this? Currently, I'm using the following code;

```
let textArray = [job.title, job.description]
    for stage in 0...1{
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont(name: "CenturyGothic", size: 20)
        label.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.text = textArray[stage]
        scrollView.addSubview(label)
    }
```

with the title and description being dynamic and pulled from a database. However, this doesnt display any text, let alone my scrollview. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use a `UITableView`?

Comment: Use table view to show dynamic data.... and you also make customised cells as per your need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you think about using a `UITextView`?

If you want to use `UILabels` I'd advise to put a vertical `UIStackView` inside your `UIScrollView` to put the `UILabels` in.

Set the the top, bottom, trailing and leading anchors to zero for scrollview to superview and for stackview to scrollview. Also set equal width constraints for superview to stackview. The vertical stack will calculate it's height automatically based on its content, but the width needs to be set from outside. The scroll view will become scrollable as soon as its content height exceeds its height.

Also don't forget to set the number of lines for the labels to zero to allow them to display an endless amount of line.

You can set all of this up programmatically or set up everything but the labels in storyboards which is way faster and reduces the amount of boilerplate code in your ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the frame of the label as well.

```
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 75, y: self.view.frame.size.height-100, width: 150, height: 35))
    label.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    label.textAlignment = .center;
    lLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Light", size: 12.0)
    label.text = message
    label.alpha = 1.0
    self.scrollView.addSubview(label)
```